# i'm trying to use python to read a file and remember where i read. next time when I run my program i would like to read from where i left

Tags: python, file, process

i'm trying to read a log file and read from the beginning at the first time and read from where i left when my program was execute again. I was able to use enumerate to get the line number when i'm reading. I wonder if I just save it to a file and use it next time my program is executed. also, not sure how to use the line number to go to the previous position of the file and read the rest of the file til EOF.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to jump to a "line number", as it actually is the number of line breaks - 1, behind the human concept of reading in English language (top - down, left to right).
For the program, you have to tell the exact position to start reading from. Use fileobj.readline() to read a whole line (including possibl linebreak and carriage return), so the pointer is always pushed to the beginning of the next line. To save the position, get it with fileobj.tell() and to set the pointer again use fileobj.seek(...).

Performance would be quicker if you read the file at once and then split+enumerate. But then you have to keep track of the consumed chars (line+cr/lf) yourself.

### // Edit 13th Mar 2016: untested sample added

Proposal: instead of saving the last reached line, save the remaining part of the log-file. It costs extra space, but simplifies handling.

```
import os

origfile = "original.log"
tempfile = "copy.tmp"

##  read from tempfile, if exists, otherwise from original log-file
if os.path.exists(tempfile):
    fp = open(tempfile)
else:
    fp = open(origfile)
lines = fp.readlines()
fp.close()

for lineno, line in enumerate(lines):
    handled = handle_line(line)   ##  call function to handle the line, 
                                  ##  return False if handling was not finished
    if not handled:      ##  if handling was not finished, save remaining lines
        fp = open(tempfile, "w")
        fp.write("".join(lines[lineno:]))
        fp.close()
        raise SystemExit()

##  when finished and all lines are handled, remove existing tempfile
if os.path.isfile(tempfile):
    os.remove(tempfile)
```

Comment: i kept a track of the line number and save this number to another file instead. This doesn't feel like an efficient way.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I didn't see your comment.

Comment: Indeed it is not efficient. If memory is not an issue, I propose to use a copy of the log-file that contains only those lines that were not evaluated. If you don't want to touch your original log file, you won't get around saving the progress, somewhere. Then using a copy of you log makes handling easier. I'll add an example to my answer.